# Convert Sparse csr matrix (422840 by 422840 ) to an array

Tags: python, arrays, object, matrix, scipy

I am trying to convert a scipy CSR matrix, A = U + D + L where A, U, D, L are `csr_matrix` object of `scipy.sparse` csr module, each of size 422840 by 422840  into a 2d array of float64. I have used `toarray()` to do the conversion. However, I am getting the error below:

```
Code line: A_test = A.toarray()
Error: `File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\soul\soul_spyder\24_july_test_soul.py:561
    A_test=A.toarray()

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_compressed.py:1051 in toarray
    out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_base.py:1298 in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.30 TiB for an array with shape (422840, 422840) and data type float64
```

I want to perform this operation: x=A\b where b is an array of float64 of dimension 422840 by 1 using `np.linalg.solve`. However, I cannot perform this operation without converting A to 2D array.
Moreover, I have also tried using `a_test = np.asarray(A)`. It gives me an ndarray of object module of size 1 (array of object module). However, I need a 2d matrix of A not an object of A. How can I convert such a big sparse matrix of size 422840 by 422840 to an array of float64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot convert your sparse array to a dense array because it is too large, hence the error (it will require too much memory to store). If you're looking to solve Ax=b for sparse matrices, use scipy's sparse solver, [`scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html).

```py
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve

x = spsolve(A,b)
```